# Just curious if this can be integrated easily

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So, I have the following equation:

$$
\frac{\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}}=-\frac{6}{t}
$$

Where the dot notation is the derivative with respect to the time variable, $t$.

How could one integrate this easily? Is it possible to invoke perhaps $\log{\dot{x}}$?

Comment: Let $w=\dot{x}$.

Comment: You are welcome. Then take the exponential and integrate again.

Comment: Little tricks go a long way! Much appreciated.